# When an application installed via apt depends on a Python package, is that package installed with apt or pip?

Tags: apt, pip

From other sources I have read that "most package managers are selfish", including APT and PIP, and they cant be expected to work well together. Therefore one should try to stick to either PIP or APT.

I know that all packages that I installed manually have been installed with PIP. But I assume that some may have been installed by APT as dependencies. When I install some random application via APT, and this application needs a few Python packages, how are they (typically) installed?

- Are they installed as APT-packages, with no PIP
- Are they installed with PIP, maybe even in a virtualenv?
- Does APT maybe even have some PIP-understanding and then it uses PIP as a tool to install Python packages?

**My reason for asking this**

I am trying to somehow clean up in my Python packages, because something got broken, and I am trying to get a better understanding of how things work so I don't break it even more. There are several packages that I cant figure out if I installed manually or if they have been installed as dependencies behind the scenes.

Comment: A stock install of Ubuntu has zero pip packages installed. Zero. Every pip package on your system was installed --directly or indirectly-- by you.

Answer (score 1):

Apt Python dependencies are **always** installed from deb packages.

A deb package that uses pip to install a dependency does not meet Debian packaging standards and won't be included in Ubuntu. Apt has no idea what pip is, nor how to use it.